# Фокус на объекте внутри canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, fabricjs

У меня в `canvas` расположено несколько объектов. Каким образом можно менять фокус на объекте программно? Например, при клике на кнопку вне `canvas`. Есть какой-нибудь метод для этого в Fabric.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, методом .setActiveObject(), например:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
});

canvas.add(circle, triangle);

canvas.renderAll();

canvas.setActiveObject(circle);
//или так:
//canvas.setActiveObject(triangle);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dko6pvjs/

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо)